# IIS Native Module RegisterModule function not invoked

Tags: c++, iis, module, native

I compiled IIS Native Module. If I compile 32bit and install in IIS. It gives error

The Module DLL ... failed to load.  The data is the error. Data is 7E000000

If I compile 64 bit and install it in IIS, I have no error but module is not working.

I added code to write to log. When I use C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe in debugging property and debug it works and writes to log but when I use it in IIS neither RegisterModule is invoked, nor any of the notifications.

Any idea what may be wrong?

In Visual Studio elevated mode I can debug the dll just fine. Both 32 bit and 64 bit work just fine in debugging. It returns the data I want to return instead of returning actual page content. It is strange that same w3wp.exe running in IIS doesn't work with dll.

Update:
It works in Windows 7 IIS but doesn't work on Windows 10 IIS. Wondering what may be the difference.

main.cpp

```
#include "precomp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
//  Global server instance
IHttpServer *                       g_pHttpServer = NULL;

//  Global module context id
PVOID                               g_pModuleContext = NULL;

#define DTTMFMT "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
#define DTTMSZ 21
static char* getDtTm(char* buff) {
    time_t t = time(0);
    strftime(buff, DTTMSZ, DTTMFMT, localtime(&t));
    return buff;
}

//  The RegisterModule entrypoint implementation.
//  This method is called by the server when the module DLL is 
//  loaded in order to create the module factory,
//  and register for server events.

HRESULT
__stdcall
RegisterModule(
    DWORD                           dwServerVersion,
    IHttpModuleRegistrationInfo *   pModuleInfo,
    IHttpServer *                   pHttpServer
)
{
    char buff[DTTMSZ];
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\inetpub\\logs\\JCFilter.txt", ios::app);
    myfile << getDtTm(buff);
    myfile << " RegisterModule.\n";
    myfile.close();
    HRESULT                             hr = S_OK;
    CJCFilterFactory  *             pFactory = NULL;

    if ( pModuleInfo == NULL || pHttpServer == NULL )
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER );
        goto Finished;
    }

    // step 1: save the IHttpServer and the module context id for future use
    g_pModuleContext = pModuleInfo->GetId();
    g_pHttpServer = pHttpServer;

    // step 2: create the module factory
    pFactory = new CJCFilterFactory();
    if ( pFactory == NULL )
    {
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32( ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY );
        goto Finished;
    }

    // step 3: register for server events
    // TODO: register for more server events here
    hr = pModuleInfo->SetRequestNotifications( pFactory, /* module factory */
                                               RQ_ACQUIRE_REQUEST_STATE | RQ_BEGIN_REQUEST/* server event mask */,
                                               0 /* server post event mask */);
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        goto Finished;
    }

    // Set the request priority.
    hr = pModuleInfo->SetPriorityForRequestNotification(
        RQ_BEGIN_REQUEST, PRIORITY_ALIAS_FIRST);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto Finished;
    }
    pFactory = NULL;

Finished:
    
    if ( pFactory != NULL )
    {
        delete pFactory;
        pFactory = NULL;
    }   

    return hr;
}
```

JCFilter.cpp

```
#include "precomp.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#define DTTMFMT "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S "
#define DTTMSZ 21
static char* getDtTm(char* buff) {
    time_t t = time(0);
    strftime(buff, DTTMSZ, DTTMFMT, localtime(&t));
    return buff;
}

//  Implementation of the OnAcquireRequestState method
REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_STATUS
CJCFilter::OnAcquireRequestState(
    IN IHttpContext *                       pHttpContext,
    IN OUT IHttpEventProvider *             pProvider
)
{
    char buff[DTTMSZ];
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("C:\\inetpub\\logs\\JCFilter.txt", ios::app);
    myfile << getDtTm(buff);
    myfile << " OnAcquireRequestState.\n";
    myfile.close();
    HRESULT                         hr = S_OK;

    // TODO: implement the AcquireRequestState module functionality

Finished:

    if ( FAILED( hr )  )
    {
        return RQ_NOTIFICATION_FINISH_REQUEST;
    }
    else
    {
        return RQ_NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE;
    }
}


    REQUEST_NOTIFICATION_STATUS
        CJCFilter::OnBeginRequest(
            IN IHttpContext* pHttpContext,
            IN IHttpEventProvider* pProvider
        )
    {
        char buff[DTTMSZ];
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("C:\\inetpub\\logs\\JCFilter.txt", ios::app);
        myfile << getDtTm(buff);
        myfile << "OnBeginRequest.\n";
        myfile.close();
        UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pProvider);

        // Create an HRESULT to receive return values from methods.
        HRESULT hr;

        // Retrieve a pointer to the response.
        IHttpResponse* pHttpResponse = pHttpContext->GetResponse();

        // Test for an error.
        if (pHttpResponse != NULL)
        {
            // Clear the existing response.
            pHttpResponse->Clear();
            // Set the MIME type to plain text.
            pHttpResponse->SetHeader(
                HttpHeaderContentType, "text/plain",
                (USHORT)strlen("text/plain"), TRUE);

            // Create a string with the response.
            PCSTR pszBuffer = "Hello World!";
            // Create a data chunk.
            HTTP_DATA_CHUNK dataChunk;
            // Set the chunk to a chunk in memory.
            dataChunk.DataChunkType = HttpDataChunkFromMemory;
            // Buffer for bytes written of data chunk.
            DWORD cbSent;

            // Set the chunk to the buffer.
            dataChunk.FromMemory.pBuffer =
                (PVOID)pszBuffer;
            // Set the chunk size to the buffer size.
            dataChunk.FromMemory.BufferLength =
                (USHORT)strlen(pszBuffer);
            // Insert the data chunk into the response.
            hr = pHttpResponse->WriteEntityChunks(
                &dataChunk, 1, FALSE, TRUE, &cbSent);

            // Test for an error.
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                // Set the HTTP status.
                pHttpResponse->SetStatus(500, "Server Error", 0, hr);
            }

            // End additional processing.
            return RQ_NOTIFICATION_FINISH_REQUEST;
        }

        // Return processing to the pipeline.
        return RQ_NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE;
    }

// TODO: implement other desired event handler methods below
```

Comment: Try to set the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" to true in iis advanced settings and try again. Open the IIS -> select Application Pools -> Advanced Settings -> Enable 32-Bit Applications to True.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. 32bit dll still gives error and 64bit doesn't give error but does nothing.

Comment: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a0e95b1-dacb-43bf-b8f1-6f8cf261f6eb/native-module-the-data-is-the-error?forum=iisextensibility](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a0e95b1-dacb-43bf-b8f1-6f8cf261f6eb/native-module-the-data-is-the-error?forum=iisextensibility).

Comment: Thanks, I already tried 32bit debug, 64bit debug, 32bit release, 64bit release. It is same.  It works perfectly fine in Windows 7 IIS but it doesn't work in Windows 10 IIS. So there is some difference with IIS version I guess.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on this message, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added main.cpp and JCFilter.cpp code in the Question.